# Using abbot to test an applet

Tags: java, testing, frameworks, applet, abbot

I am working through the examples in the Abbot download and I am not quite clear on how to launch and test an applet using Abbot. The FAQ says to use Appletviewer but its "usage" specifies an xml format. So I am a bit confused as to how to launch an applet.

Is there a snippet of code anywhere that I can see how this is done from an abbot junit test ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swing and record and play testing take a look at Marathon open source test tool. It also generates scripts that can be modified.